# Who was the person that told Satoshi "You will not find a solution to political problems in cryptography"?

Tags: satoshi

I think this answer to a statement by Satoshi in the cryptography mailing list is one of the most interesting and revealing things he's said:

The original statement:

> You will not find a solution to political problems in cryptography.

Satoshi's answer:

> Yes, but we can win a major battle in the arms race and gain a new territory of freedom for several years. Governments are good at cutting off the heads of a centrally controlled 
>   networks like Napster, but pure P2P networks like Gnutella and Tor seem to be holding their own.

source:
https://www.mail-archive.com/cryptography@metzdowd.com/msg09971.html

However, it seems like the original statement in the mailing list that Satoshi is replying to seems to have been made off of the mailing list thus the full message and the identity of the person is unknown. Who was this person and what was his full message?

Answer (score 5):

It seems that no-one except Satoshi and the original author knows, as indeed the correspondence was not made on the mailing list and the rest of the message was not made public.

Answer (score 1):

[Here is a dump of all the messages in the month](http://www.metzdowd.com/pipermail/cryptography/2008-November.txt)

I can't find the exact phrase "You will not find a solution to political problems in cryptography." anywhere else but Satoshi's message. (However it has been noted by others investigating the origin of the question, in that the next message is from the moderator requesting no more politics.) so did Satoshi misinterpret this as a question? was it an off-list message? I think as @MeshColider states "no-one except Satoshi and the original author knows"